# type object 'Base' has no attribute '_decl_class_registry'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am upgrading a library to a recent version of SQLAlchemy and I am getting this error

> type object 'Base' has no attribute '_decl_class_registry'

On line

```
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

Base._decl_class_registry
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What were you using it for?  (Related [issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6080)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem. Because of my upgrade of sqlalchemy looks like there is a change in the base code.

use this instead to accomplish the same

```
Base.registry._class_registry.values()
```

Comment: Hi Ajay Reddy, where should we insert this statement?